# Eclipse and class import issues

Tags: java, eclipse, import

I am experiencing an odd behaviour using Eclipse: I am trying to use an `ArrayList` so if I try to import the class and then empoy it, I get a nasty error.

```
//... bunch of other imports

//Warning: unused import
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TagHandler {
    public static <ArrayList>Tag getRows(int id) throws SQLException {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM Tag WHERE id = ?";

        //Unexpected type error
        ArrayList<Tag> list = null;

        ResultSet rs = null;

// ... more code ...
}
```

but if I instantiate an object using the absolute path of the package, Eclipse is ok with that.

```
//... bunch of other imports

public class TagHandler {
    public static <ArrayList>Tag getRows(int id) throws SQLException {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM Tag WHERE id = ?";

        //Works fine
        java.util.ArrayList<Tag> list = null;

        ResultSet rs = null;

// ... more code ...
}
```

I have written other classes and I have always imported the `ArrayList` class and used it without a hitch, so what could possibly be wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are declaring a generic type parameter for your method that shadows the `ArrayList` type

```
public static <ArrayList> Tag getRows(int id) throws SQLException {
               ^
```

If you use the simple name `ArrayList`, you are referring to that type variable, not the actual `java.util.ArrayList` type.

Your method was equivalent to

```
public static <T> Tag getRows(int id) throws SQLException {
    String query = "SELECT * FROM Tag WHERE id = ?";

    //Unexpected type error
    T<Tag> list = null;

    ResultSet rs = null;
```

which is not syntactically correct. You probably meant `ArrayList<Tag>` instead of `<ArrayList>Tag`.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Eclipse was signaling the error elsewhere and I did't notice where the actual problem lied.

Answer (score 2):

That is because the declaration of your static method is incorrect

```
public static <ArrayList>Tag getRows(int id) throws SQLException
```

should be

```
public static ArrayList<Tag> getRows(int id) throws SQLException
```

try fixing your static method and importing `ArrayList` with an import at the top of the file

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TagHandler {
  public static ArrayList<Tag> getRows(int id) throws SQLException {
    String query = "SELECT * FROM Tag WHERE id = ?";

    ArrayList<Tag> list = null;

    ResultSet rs = null;

// ... more code ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
 public static ArrayList<Tag> getRows(int id) throws SQLException
```